# Shopify - Mobile Image Loading on Desktop For 1 Sec - Even though It is Hidden

Tags: css, mobile, shopify, lazy-loading

I have 2x promo banners one for desktop (#usp-banner), one for mobile (#usp-banner2).

Each one should only be displaying to their respective sizes because of the use of the .css:

**layout.min.css**
`#usp-banner2{display:none}html{padding-bottom:0!important}...`

**custom.css**

```
#usp-banner2{display:none}

@media (max-width:767px){
  #usp-banner{display:none!important}
  #usp-banner2{display:inline}
}
```

Upon loading the page on Desktop or Mobile we see BOTH banners and their correct banner hides after about 1 sec. `Source:` https://www.ivyandfig.com

I am fairly new to Shopify, but am able to modify templates. I'm curious is this due to the way .css is loaded?

Anyone have suggestions on how to ensure the css is being loaded before the images display (as I am assuming this is part of what is happening)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most of the stylesheets and scripts on your site are being loaded via JavaScript. That JavaScript is triggered much later as compared to when the initial content is visible on your site.

As you have guessed, this is happening because CSS is loaded much later so for the time being both images are visible.

As that part is a Shopify section, a quick fix is to include the related CSS rules inside section. More of that is available on [Shopify Documentation for Sections](https://help.shopify.com/en/themes/development/sections#javascript-and-stylesheet-tags).

Another fix may be is to create a separate stylesheet with only rules like that CSS reset, hide and show content etc and include it via link tag in header.

You can also use some logic based on inline styles by hiding both initially and then display later via JavaScript.